# How to solve this IndexError?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, data-indexing-techniques

I have created a training dataframe **Traindata** as following:

```
dataFile='/content/drive/Colab Notebooks/.../Normal_Anomalous_8Digits.csv'
data8=pd.read_csv(dataFile)
```

And **Traindata** looks like the following: Here Output is predicted variable which is not included in test data.

```
         Col1        Col2     Output
0      0.001655   0.464986      1
1      0.943110   0.902166      0
2      0.071235   0.674283      1
...      ...        ...         ..
1007   0.698048   0.058458      1
1008   0.289333   0.702763      1
1009 rows × 3 columns
```

Now the model is trained as following commands:

```
from pgmpy.models import BayesianModel, BayesianNetwork
from pgmpy.estimators import MaximumLikelihoodEstimator
model = BayesianNetwork([('Col1', 'Output'), ('Col2', 'Output')])
model.fit(data8, estimator=MaximumLikelihoodEstimator)
```

I have created a tested dataframe **dataP** by following method:

```
Col1=pickle.load(open('/content/drive/Colab Notebooks/.../col1.pickle', 'rb'))
Col2=pickle.load(open('/content/drive/ColabNotebooks/.../col2.pickle', 'rb'))
dataT=np.array([Col1[:179], Col2]).T
#Col1 has 184 rows while Col2 has 179 rows, so I reduced the rows of col1 to make concatenation easy.
dataP=pd.DataFrame(dataT, columns=['Col1','Col2'])
dataP.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

I have a dataframe **dataP** as:

```
       Col1     Col2
0    0.832946  0.583372
1    0.783141  0.583948
2    0.745327  0.587644
3    0.762367  0.585629
4    0.783265  0.590721
..        ...       ...
174  0.686461  0.578358
175  0.689001  0.583951
176  0.683956  0.577511
177  0.687347  0.584231
178  0.695827  0.578313

[179 rows x 2 columns]
```

When I passed this dataframe to my model for prediction :

```
Y=model.predict(dataP)
```

It raises the following index error:

```
IndexError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-489f2f25f1bc> in <module>()
 ----> 2 Y=model.predict(dataP)
5 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py in __get_result(self)
    382     def __get_result(self):
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:
    386             return self._result

 IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), 
 numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Then I checked the indices of dataframe as

```
print(dataP.index)
```

OUTPUT

```
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=179, step=1)
```

Then I check the datatype of my index as

```
dataP.index.is_numeric()
dataP.index.is_integers()
```

In both of above cases, it gives

```
TRUE
TRUE
```

Now if the indices of dataframe **dataP** is integers, then why it is raising such an error. Kindly guide me in this respect.

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried resetting the index using [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)?

Comment: Yes! I have tried. Still the same error raises.

Comment: Which library and learning method do you use, is it sklearn? Do you pass the features directly as a pandas dataframe? The problem is likely about how `dataP` is created, but the code doesn't show it.

Comment: In dataP, I have combine two separate arrays col1 and col2. And then convert it to dataframe. And model is created by bayesianNetwork. I have edited the question above. kindly review it.